# SQLalchemy not working when trying to connect with odbc database

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, urllib, pyodbc

I currently use the pyodbc library to connect to my MS SQL database with the following code.

**import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

server =
database =
username =
password =

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

df = pd.read_sql("select * from dbo.DATA_LOG where timestamp LIKE '2023-06-06%'",cnxn)**

This code works and I am able to read my database and underlying tables. But it gives me the following user warning *"UserWarning:pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy." *

I tried to use the following code for SQLAlchemy but it doesn't work and I am unable to find what is the error in this code.

import pyodbc
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('SERVER=server_name;DATABASE=database_name;UID=username;PWD=password')
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

connection = engine.connect()

I get the following error "InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/rvf5)"

I dont know the default driver but it was not necessary for the previous code so i wonder if that's the bottleneck here.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Debug within VS Code and i also used chatgpt.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html#dsn-connections

Comment: thank you for your response but I followed this guide but it doesn't work. I keep getting the same error.